# Mockito verify fails when method takes a function as argument

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I have a Scala test which uses Mockito to verify that certain DataFrame transformations are invoked.   I broke it down to this simple problematic example

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.mockito.{Mockito, MockitoSugar}

class SimpleTest extends  AnyFunSuite{

  def withGreeting(df: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
    df.withColumn("greeting", lit("hello"))
  }

  test("sample test") {
    val mockDF = MockitoSugar.mock[DataFrame]
    val mockDF2 = MockitoSugar.mock[DataFrame]
    MockitoSugar.doReturn(mockDF2).when(mockDF).transform(withGreeting)
    mockDF.transform(withGreeting)
    val orderVerifier = Mockito.inOrder(mockDF)
    orderVerifier.verify(mockDF).transform(withGreeting)
  }

}
```

I'm trying to assert that the transform was called on my mockDF, but it fails with

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
dataset.transform(<function1>);
-> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.transform(Dataset.scala:2182)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
dataset.transform(<function1>);
```

Why would the verify fail in this case?

Comment: If you want Mockito to assert that an argument is the expected argument it needs equality checks to work. Those do not work automatically on anonymous functions. Every `withGreeting` creates a new closure for `x => withGreeting(x)` and those are considered different. Maybe you don't have to check which function `transform` is being called with and just have the mock blindly return your prepared result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save lambda expression argument for `transform` as `val` for correct testing and pass it to all `transform` calls:

```
def withGreeting(df: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn("greeting", lit("hello"))
}

test("sample test") {
  val mockDF = MockitoSugar.mock[DataFrame]
  val mockDF2 = MockitoSugar.mock[DataFrame]
  val withGreetingExpression = df => withGreeting(df)
  MockitoSugar.doReturn(mockDF2).when(mockDF).transform(withGreetingExpression)
  mockDF.transform(withGreetingExpression)
  val orderVerifier = Mockito.inOrder(mockDF)
  orderVerifier.verify(mockDF).transform(withGreetingExpression)
}
```

Mockito requires to provide same (or equal) arguments to the mocked functions calls. When you are passing lambda expression without saving each call `transform(withGreeting)` creates new object `Function[DataFrame, DataFrame]`

`transform(withGreeting)`

is the same as:

```
transform(new Function[DataFrame, DataFrame] {
  override def apply(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = withGreeting(df)
})
```

And they aren't equal to each other - this is the cause of error message:
`Argument(s) are different!`

For example, try to execute:

```
println(((df: DataFrame) => withGreeting(df)) == ((df: DataFrame) => withGreeting(df))) //false
```

You can read more about objects equality in java (in the scala it's same):

- [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Comparing_Objects)
- [javaworld.com](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072762/object-equality.html)